# Can't find any online and idle self-hosted runner in the current repository

Tags: github-actions

When I run GitHub Actions, shows error:

```
Can't find any online and idle self-hosted runner in the current repository, account/organization that matches the required labels: 'macos-11.1'
Waiting for a self-hosted runner to pickup this job...
```

I want to run GitHub Actions on macos-11.1, is the GitHub Actions did not support macos-11.1? what should I do to avoid this problem? I know the GitHub Actions support macos 11.1 from https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md

this is my script:

```
jobs:
  build:
    #
    # more macOS version:
    # https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md
    #
    runs-on: macos-11.1
```

Comment: From https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments it should be `macos-11`.